# GDB Api lookup_symbol does not get symbol address

Tags: api, debugging, gdb

This is a question about changing GDB code to add my own CLI to it.

I'm using lookup_symbol("XYZ", ...) to find a global system address in my coredump. The API succeeds - i.e, gets the symbol data struct with symbol name, but no address.

'print XYZ' works fine!

What can I change to get the symbol address correctly.